# Are these two questions duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

1. [What is the singular source of Star Wars canonization?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/what-is-the-singular-source-of-star-wars-canonization)
2. [How is canonicity of derivative works determined for Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars)

I think they might be duplicates but for some reason can't quite make up my mind.

What does the community think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're not duplicates.  The bottom one is just asking about the levels of canon in the Star Wars universe (I just voted to close that as there's a Wikipedia article that explains that).

The top one, based on the comments, is asking about the process of making a work canon.  As in, how do writers/game makers/etc have their work included in the Star Wars canon.  This is asking more about the process of adding to the canon, and not the categorization of the existing canon.

Comment: Got it. First one needs to be edited to clarify that \*hint\* \*hint* :)